# SQL query to get three most recent records by customer

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table of orders and am looking to get the three most recent orders by customer id

```
customer    orderID     orderDate     
1           234          2018-01-01    
1           236          2017-02-01       
3           256          20157-03-01
```

I was able to use row number () to identify the row number of each line in the table, but is there a way to get the three most recent orders by customer id? Some customers do have less than 3 orders while others have more than 10 orders so I wasn't able to specify by the row number.

Does anyone have recommendations for a different option?

Comment: You can use orderDate to retrieve recent orders for customer. However if you would have had timestamp it would help retrieving orders placed by a customer on the same day as well.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an interesting approach using `apply` (and assuming you have a `customers` table):

```
select o.*
from customers c cross apply
     (select top 3 o.*
      from orders o
      where o.customerid = c.customerid
      order by orderdate desc
     ) o;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `partition by`;

```
select customerid, orderid,orderdate from (
select t.customerid, t.orderid,t.orderdate
,row_number() over (partition by t.customerid order by t.orderDate desc) as mostRecently
from samplecustomers t)
Records where mostRecently < 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM orders 
 WHERE customer = 1 
 ORDER BY orderDate ASC limit 3
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: This does not work for all customers. I think he wants a generic way of doing this, something like partitions.

Comment: @NikhilBaby . . . More relevantly, this doesn't work in SQL Server at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
SELECT result.customer
     , result.orderID
     , result.orderDate
 FROM
     (
     SELECT Temp.customer
          , Temp.orderID
          , Temp.orderDate
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Temp.customer 
                                  ORDER BY Temp.orderDate DESC) AS MR
      FROM YourTable AS Temp
     )  AS result
WHERE result.MR <= 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
select a.Customer, a.orderID, a.orderDate   
from orders a  
where a.orderID in  
(  
select top 3 b.orderID  
from orders b  
where b.Customer = a.Customer  
order by b.orderDate desc  
)  
order by a.Customer, a.orderID, a.orderDate
```